# Selenium / TestNG: 'Unable to take a screenshot of Failed test case using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I am trying to write a test case that simulates a GMail Login. I'm receiving the following error when trying to take a screenshot of the failed test case:
Appended whole code snippet , Unable to take screenshot & save the screenshot.

Error shown:

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest Fail_Test || java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`

Code snippet:

```
 @Test
    public void login_gmail() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/neha.sharma/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver drv=new ChromeDriver();
    drv.get("http://www.gmail.com");
    drv.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("nehasharma@gmail.com"); //USERNAME ENTRY
    Thread.sleep(6000);

    WebElement eleme = drv.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]")); //NEXT BUTTON CLICK
     JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)drv;
     executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", eleme);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    drv.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("abcd234"); // PASSWORD ENTRY
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    //drv.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]")).click();
    WebElement eleme2 = drv.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='passwordNext']/content/span")); // NEXT BUTTON CLICK AFTER ENTERING PASSWORD
    JavascriptExecutor executor1 = (JavascriptExecutor)drv;
    executor1.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", eleme2);
    String Pass_Result= eleme2.getText();
    AssertJUnit.assertEquals(Pass_Result, "NEXT");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @AfterTest
         void Fail_Test(ITestResult Result) throws IOException

    {

            if (ITestResult.FAILURE==Result.getStatus())
            {
                TakesScreenshot ts= (TakesScreenshot)drv;
                File Source=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(Source, new File("D:\\TestScreen.png"));
                System.out.print("Screenshot taken");
             }
    }
```

Please help me out in rectifying this code snippet.

Comment: what is the the return type of ITestResult?

Comment: Which TestNG version are you using?

Comment: I am using TestNG version 6.11.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am right or not, but I think you need to pass the value

```
void fail_test(String name,int name){

}
```

and I think you should keep data type not the name  ie, `String ITestResult`

Answer (score 0):

`ITestResult` is not allowed on `@AfterTest` methods. But it is possible on `@AfterMethod` (which is, I think, the annotation you wanted to use).

So, just replace `@AfterTest` by `@AfterMethod`.

Comment: okay i have changed the annotation , but still i m unable to take a screenshot of Failed  test case.